# How to load 15.000.000 registers into a table with pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, etl

I have created an ETL process with Pentaho that selects data from a table in a Database and load this into another database.

The main problem that I have to make front is that for 1.500.000 rows it takes 6 hours. The full table is 15.000.000 and I have to load 5 tables like that.

Can anyone explain how is supposed to load a large size of data with pentaho?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a database question not a PDI question as such. The limiting factor will almost always be either the speed by which the source database can deliver the data or the write performance of there target db. Unless you say which database you are using it is hard to suggest something.

Comment: It seems there is a bottle neck in your network while fetching the data from database? afaik your data shouldn't take 6hrs to load but way lesser. Expecting it to complete in 30min max. Can you ask your dbadmin team to check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never had problem with volume with Pentaho PDI. Check the following in order.

> Can you check the problem is really coming from Pentaho: what happens if you drop the query in SQL-Developer or Toad or SQL-IDE-Fancy-JDBC-Compilant.

In principle, PDI is meant to import data with a `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ...` and do all the rest in the transformation. I have a set of transformation here which take hours to execute because they do complex queries. The problem is not due to PDI but complexity of the query. The solutions is to export the GROUP BY and SELECT FROM (SELECT...) into PDI steps, which can start before the query result is finished. The result is like 4 hours to 56 seconds. No joke.

> What is your memory size? It is defined in the spoon.bat / spoon.sh.

Near the end you have a line which looks like `PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1024m" "-Xmx4096m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"`. The important parameter is `-Xmx...`. If it is `-Xmx256K`, your jvm has only 256KB of RAM to work with.

Change it to 1/2 or 3/4 of the available memory, in order to leave room for the other processes.

> Is the output step the bottleneck? Check by disabling it and watch you clock during the run.

If it is long , increase the commit size and allow batch inserts.

Disable all the index and constraints and restore them when loaded. You have nice SQL script executor steps to automate that, but check first manually then in a job, otherwise the reset index may trigger before to load begins.

You have also to check that you do not lock your self: as PDI launches the steps alltogether, you may have truncates which are waiting on another truncate to unlock. If you are not in an never ending block, it may take quite while before to db is able to cascade everything.

Answer (score 1):

There's no fixed answer covering all possible performance issues. You'll need to identify the bottlenecks and solve them in your environment.

If you look at the Metrics tab while running the job in Spoon, you can often see at which step the rows/s rate drops. It will be the one with the full input buffer and empty output buffer.

To get some idea of the maximum performance of the job, you can test each component individually.

- Connect the Table Input to a dummy step only and see how many rows/s it reaches.
- Define a Generate Rows step with all the fields that go to your destination and some representative data and connect it to the Table Output step. Again, check the rows/s to see the destination database's throughput.
- Start connecting more steps/transformations to your Table Input and see where performance goes down.

Once you know your bottlenecks, you'll need to figure out the solutions. Bulk load steps often help the output rate. If network lag is holding you back, you might want to dump data to compressed files first and copy those locally. If your Table input has joins or where clauses, make sure the source database has the correct indexes to use, or change your query.

Comment: @Maik You can improve the performance of data loading into table in context.xml by adding below parameters.                                                            useServerPrepStmts=false
rewriteBatchedStatements=true
useCompression=true